# Is it natural and correct to say "get into an embarrassing situation"?

Tags: collocations

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say *get into an embarrassing situation*? For example:

> The other day **I got into an embarrassing situation**, but now I'm over it.

What I'm trying to say is that something awkward happened to me. If it's not natural, what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: [Here's the usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+into+an+embarrassing+situation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20into%20an%20embarrassing%20situation%3B%2Cc0) Why are you doubtful?

Comment: Note that ***I got into** [some situation]* implies ***I did things*** causing me to be in that situation. But ***something happened to me*** implies ***I was a "passive victim" of circumstances***.